# What do all the values mean in the 'server details' in battlelog?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

If you visit the server page of a server on Battlelog, there is a block of values called "SERVER DETAILS", which appears to be the settings of the server. What do all these values mean?

[image]

I'm most interested in "New players server" but a complete list of all these items would be really apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**New players server = rank 10 or lower**

They all mean exactly what they say, depending on where you are seeing the info you can select the option and it will give you more detail, like in the server setup screen.

In the case of `New players server` it could change on each update, but the last changelog I could find it says that rank 10 or lower.

> http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/forum/threadview/2955065240539184940/last/